# declaring a generic type "of a generic type"

Tags: delphi, freepascal

Not exactly sure how to pose this question, but using lazarus v1.8.2 I am attempting to define a generic type, using another generic type:

```
//initial interface
  IOtherInterface<T> = interface
    function ExampleFunction : T;
  end;
  //some generic record
  TSomething<T> = record
    Something : T;
  end;
 //attempting to further genericize
  IOtherSomething<T> = IOtherInterface<TSomething<T>>;
```

The error I receive is: 
`Fatal: Syntax error, "," expected but "<" found`

I'm using mode delphi as I want to remain compliant for both compilers. I feel pretty confident that I've done this sort of specialization in delphi before, but don't have great access to a professional version to test.
Is this a limitation to on FPC side of things, or perhaps am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: This won't compile on Delphi as well.

Comment: I've edited showing double specialization that compiles in delphi

Comment: I reverted the edit. The edit changed the question and invalidated the answers by asking a different question. If you want to ask another question, you would need a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what

```
 IOtherSomething<T> = IOtherInterface<TSomething<T>>;
```

is meant to achieve here. If you are trying to extend the interface you need something like

```
IOtherSomething<T> = interface(IOtherInterface<TSomething<T>>)
end;
```

which does compile in Delphi. I don't have Lazarus to test.

If this is not what you are trying to do I will delete the answer.

If it is, I will edit to remove these comments.

Comment: I've edited my question now to show extending the interface, however it still does not compile in lazarus (does in Delphi)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you should still declare IOtherInterface and later specialize it with TSomething .

Generics.Collections works this way (with TPair in the role of TSomething ).

Anyway, FPC fixes has a problem with double specializations, it sees >> or << as shift tokens. This is fixed in trunk

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question. What code should be used?

Comment: @Marco van de Voort so this is a confirmed issue with the current version of FPC? Is there a link to some kind of issue you can provide?
Also, is this the correct location for trunk? https://svn.freepascal.org/svn/lazarus/trunk/

Comment: actually, think I found it, my above was just for lazarus not fpc,
ftp://ftp.freepascal.org/pub/fpc/snapshot/trunk/

Comment: In C++, to avoid `<<` and `>>`problems, people simply write `< <`and `> >`, i.e. with a space inbetween.